# Can I restore a Snow Leopard backup onto a Lion machine?

Tags: snow-leopard, backup, time-machine, macos, restore

So I am a little confused and slightly worried, and I was wondering if someone could answer this.

I have a Time Machine backup saved on an external HD for my Mac mini that is running the latest version of Snow Leopard.

If I buy a new computer running Lion, will there be issues with using my Snow Leopard back-up to put my files on the new machine running Lion? Is that even possible? Or do I have to update my old computer to Lion first, and make a back-up before moving to the new computer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not complicated at all. I can't point to a current Lion Apple support doc but I just moved my old snow leopard time machine backup to my new Lion install.

Simply launch **Migration Assistant**, select your Time Machine backup and select which settings and users to copy. It doesn't care that your backup is a Snow Leopard backup.

For more information here is an article about how to use Migration Assistant in Snow Leopard. It is virtually the same in Lion.

http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.6/en/27921.html

Answer (score 2):

I can't say if you can run migration directly but hope you can. If not, it's still not that bad so don't be overly worried :-)

Worst case, you will have to use something like Disk Utility to restore one of the Time Machine snapshot folders to a volume (like an external drive) where it will look close enough like a bootable external drive.

From there you should have no issues using the Migration Assistant to migrate that old data (either directly from the Time Machine folder - or copied onto a hard drive) just like the migration assistant supports to migrate from an external drive.

In the past, I have been able to use Disk Utility to make a DMG file from a Time Machine folder and use Migration Assistant on 10.6 to migrate that data - but I haven't really tested it with Lion yet.

You will be able to do it with some time and spare cheap USB hard drive (or perhaps enough drive space for a whole image copy of one snapshot in time) - it's just a matter of how many steps and disk space are needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can restore files on Lion from Time Machine. See @Steve Moser's answer for the OS.