# Snow Leopard Time Machine backups are not visible in Lion

Tags: macos, time-machine, backup

I upgraded to Lion recently.  I noticed tonight that backups performed on Snow Leopard do not show in the Time Machine interface so I cannot restore from them.  If I browse my backup volume I can see my backups exist right back to December 2009.  How do I get Time Machine in Lion to recognize my old backups?

Comment: Related information: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17804/can-i-restore-a-snow-leopard-backup-onto-a-lion-machine

Comment: Thanks Philip that's useful information but doesn't help me achieve what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, without doing anything apart from rebooting my Mac and my NAS drive the backups are now visible so I wasted 50 points on a bounty I didn't need.  Oh well...

Comment: And here goes quote from IT Crowd: “Have you tried to turn it off and on again?” ;-)

Comment: Haha, well being in I.T. I tried that several times but to no avail.  Maybe there's a specific number of times I needed to turn it off and on.  ;o)

Comment: Actually yes, it's 3, "Threefold repetition"... Maybe you can award the points to someone and they can award them back; Then your points are not wasted as you put it.